# html make active sidebar tab continue body gradient color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am working on my website sidebar, I have a couple different colors going on, the page you're currently on will have the id='currentPage' (currently set to red), and my main body background will have a gradient. I'm trying to make my active tab color appear transparent, so instead of being red, it will continue the gradient of the body background seamlessly. I've tried setting the activeTab background to have zero opacity but that will just show the sidebar background color, Is there some way to tell my activeTab to continue the gradient from my body color?

```
/* active tab color */
#currentPage { 
  background: #dc3545; 
} 

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel='icon' href='{{ icon }}' type='image/x-icon' />
    <title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<style>
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b81717;
    border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    /* background: rgb(11, 223, 212); */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-left:11px
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    /*  NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
    background: #63c23e; 
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 20px;
    /* background: #6d7fcc; */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    /* padding: 20px 0; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------age page colors------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        color: pink
        display: inline;
    }
}

#imageModal{
    z-index:3;
}

/* Sidebar expand/collapse button */
#sidebarCollapse{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    
    margin-left: 84%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0 ,0, 0, .3);
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Bottom of sidebar image stuff */
.responsive {
    width: 90%;
    bottom:20px;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

/* color image title */
#colorsTitle{
    font-size:15px;
    margin-left: 29%;
}

/* color image text formatting */
#pageColorsText{
    font-size:15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    /*
    margin-left: 29%;
    */
}

.imageDetails{
display: inline-block;
}

.imageDetailsText{
text-align: center;
}

/* active tab color */
#currentPage { 
  background: #dc3545; 
} 


</style>

<nav id="sidebar">

        <div id="sidebarTop" class="sidebar-header">
            <h3 style="text-size:22px">website title</h3> <button id="sidebarCollapse"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/24/000000/menu.png"></button> <!-- id='sidebutton' -->
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components sideBarOption">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#projectsSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" class="dropdown-toggle ">Projects</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled show " id="projectsSubmenu">
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id='currentPage'>website.biz</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">more projects</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contactSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="contactSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Email</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Github</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Resume</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#blogSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Blog</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="blogSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Post 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Post 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Post 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Post 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="sidebar-footer imageDetails">
            <a class="imageDetailsText">Image page colors</a><br>
            <!-- img 1 -->
            <img id="colorImageDisplay" style="display: block;" class="responsive" alt="image alt descr" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTcyZWMzMTgtZmM0ZC00NzM2LWEzNjEtYTJhMTgzYmI1MDllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjUyNDk2ODc@._V1_.jpg">
            <!-- img 2 
            <img id="colorImageDisplay" style="display: block;" class="responsive" alt="image alt descr" src="https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/binaries/content/gallery/metofficegovuk/hero-images/weather/cloud/altocumulus.jpg"> -->
            
            
            
            <div id="pageColorsText">
                <a id="color1Hex">Color 1: #657856</a><br>
                <a id="color2Hex">Color 2: #657856</a><br>
                <a id="color3Hex">Color 3: #657856</a><br>
                <a id="color4Hex">Color 4: #657856</a><br>
                <a id="color5Hex">Color 5: #657856</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: when an active tab is transparent you will get the background of your sidebar

Answer (score 0):

You need to give active and all your container elements 'background: transparent', and assign the green color directly to each inner element. It's going to require redoing some of your current classes/html structure as margin settings are interfering.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel='icon' href='{{ icon }}' type='image/x-icon' />
    <title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<style>
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b81717;
    border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    /* background: rgb(11, 223, 212); */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-left:11px
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    /*  NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
   /* background: #63c23e; */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 20px;
    /* background: #6d7fcc; */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    /* padding: 20px 0; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;  
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
    
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------age page colors------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        color: pink
        display: inline;
    }
}

#imageModal{
    z-index:3;
}

/* Sidebar expand/collapse button */
#sidebarCollapse{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    
    margin-left: 84%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0 ,0, 0, .3);
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Bottom of sidebar image stuff */
.responsive {
    width: 90%;
    bottom:20px;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

/* color image title */
#colorsTitle{
    font-size:15px;
    margin-left: 29%;
}

/* color image text formatting */
#pageColorsText{
    font-size:15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    /*
    margin-left: 29%;
    */
}

.imageDetails{
display: inline-block;
}

.imageDetailsText{
text-align: center;
}

/* active tab color */
#currentPage { 
  background: transparent; 
} 

a, h3, div {
  background: #63c23e;
}

</style>

<nav id="sidebar">

        <div id="sidebarTop" class="sidebar-header">
            <h3 style="text-size:22px">website title</h3> <button id="sidebarCollapse"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/24/000000/menu.png"></button> <!-- id='sidebutton' -->
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components sideBarOption">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#projectsSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" class="dropdown-toggle ">Projects</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled show " id="projectsSubmenu">
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id='currentPage'>website.biz</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">more projects</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contactSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="contactSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Email</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Github</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Resume</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#blogSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Blog</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="blogSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Post 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Post 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Post 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Post 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="sidebar-footer imageDetails">
            <a class="imageDetailsText">Image page colors</a><br>
            <!-- img 1 -->
            <img id="colorImageDisplay" style="display: block;" class="responsive" alt="image alt descr" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTcyZWMzMTgtZmM0ZC00NzM2LWEzNjEtYTJhMTgzYmI1MDllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjUyNDk2ODc@._V1_.jpg">
            <!-- img 2 
            <img id="colorImageDisplay" style="display: block;" class="responsive" alt="image alt descr" src="https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/binaries/content/gallery/metofficegovuk/hero-images/weather/cloud/altocumulus.jpg"> -->
            
            
            
            <div id="pageColorsText">
                <a id="color1Hex">Color 1: #657856</a><br>
                <a id="color2Hex">Color 2: #657856</a><br>
                <a id="color3Hex">Color 3: #657856</a><br>
                <a id="color4Hex">Color 4: #657856</a><br>
                <a id="color5Hex">Color 5: #657856</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
```